# Why can't emacs on OSX in iTerm2 not see C-S-<up>?

Tags: macos, emacs, zsh, iterm

I have the following keyboard shortcut in my init.el

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-S-<up>") 'move-line-up)
```

This works great in Cocoa Emacs.app, but when running emacs in console mode in iTerm2 it seems that they keys never make it to emacs.

I tried running the following in emacs

```
(read-key-sequence "?")
```

And entering `C-S-<up>` in the prompt but it was never received. That makes me think that either iTerm2 or zsh is stealing the keystrokes. Any ideas on how to debug this? Or better yet answers?

Comment: Not really relevant since you don't report this as happening, but Control-Shift-<up> for me triggers a slow-motion transition to Mission Control.

Comment: Well worth checking that you've switched off all the Mission Control keyboard actions (that you don't want.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be that it's iTerm intercepting things.

You might find [this site](http://offbytwo.com/2012/01/15/emacs-plus-paredit-under-terminal.html) helpful. It says:

> Select **Profiles > Open Profiles…** from the menu bar, or press Command-O and take a look at the default profile. Click on the **Keys** section. While you are here verify you have **Left Option** and **Right Option** as `+Esc`.
>
> For the arrow key fixes though you will need to add a series of key shortcuts. The easiest way to get started is select **Load Preset… > xterm Defaults**

Comment: Load Preset... > xterm Defaults, did the trick. Thanks so much! :)